# By adding "?login - failed" code unable to access my dashboard

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

I am using the following snippet code to stop customer redirect after wrong password or empty username and password in my WordPress theme.

But by adding this code i am unable to access my admin dashboard from url like "www.example.com/ignite" or "www.example.com/wp-admin"

```
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'elementor_form_login_fail', 9999999 );
function elementor_form_login_fail( $username ) {
   $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
  if ((!empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') )) {
        wp_redirect(preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $referrer) . '/?login=failed' );
        exit;
   }
}


add_action( 'wp_authenticate', 'elementor_form_login_empty', 1, 2 );
function elementor_form_login_empty( $username, $pwd ) {
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
    
 if ( empty( $username ) || empty( $pwd ) ) {
    
     if ((!strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') )) {
       wp_redirect(preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $referrer) . '/?login=failed' );
      exit;
    }
   exit();
 }
}
```

Comment: '9999999' is an abnormally high priority. Perhaps something runs prior to this that causes the problem. Do you get the same results if you set the priority to something lower like 5 or 10?

Comment: With low priority this will redirect to admin- login page after wrong id and password.